# Dapper Contrib Output Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm research about Dapper Contrib stored procedure and I don't know how to get value output parameter from the procedure.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomPaging]
    @SkipCount INT,
    @PageSize INT, /*record in 1 page*/
    @TotalRows INT OUTPUT /*tong record*/
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Product

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Product
    ORDER BY ProductID 
        OFFSET @SkipCount ROW FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

And this is my Dapper contrib query:

```
db.Query<Models.Product>("spCustomPaging", new { SkipCount = skip, PageSize = pageSize }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

How I can get the TotalRow from the stored procedure with Dapper Contrib?

Sorry for my bad English and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `DynamicParameters` be the parameter that can declare `ParameterDirection.Output` for the parameter which you want to be output, then we can use `Get<int>` to get the output value.

```
var params = new DynamicParameters();
params.Add("@SkipCount",skip);
params.Add("@PageSize",pageSize);
params.Add("@TotalRows", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

db.Query<Models.Product>("spCustomPaging", params, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

var output = params.Get<int>("@TotalRows");
```